# setup.py fails to install google-cloud-pubsub

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to prepare `setup.py` that will install all necessary dependencies, including google-cloud-pubsub. However, `python setup.py install` fails with

```
pkg_resources.UnknownExtra: googleapis-common-protos 1.6.0b6 has no such extra feature 'grpc'
```

The weird thing is that I can install those dependencies through `pip install` in my virtualenv.

How can I fix it or get around it? I use Python 2.7.15.

Here's minimal configuration to reproduce the problem:

**setup.py**

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='example',
    install_requires=['google-cloud-pubsub']
)
```

Comment: It looks like python2.7 support for this library will be deprecated at the start of 2020, just a heads up. I am able to replicate the issue on my anaconda 2.7 test env

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `setup.py` use the following:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='example',
    install_requires=['google-cloud-pubsub', 'googleapis-common-protos==1.5.3']
)
```

That seems to get around it